# Jmeter post request appear as get request while exceuting (ASP DOTNET)

Tags: asp.net, testing, automation, jmeter

I have done a simple scenario of login in ASP dot net application. But the request which i have send as post while logging in appears as GET in the request page while executing. The first image is the Screenshot of HTTP Request and the second one is Screenshot for the request details while execution.How to convert that request to POST request? Also added the screenshot of the response data showing "Object moved to here " message.

[image: Screenshot of HTTP Request]

[image: Screenshot for the request details while execution]

[image: object moved here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No , in fact what happened is that your Post request had a redirect (302) which led to a second request being emitted in Get.

I can see your node has children so jmeter shows the last request, unfold it and click on the first request

Comment: Yes.. the node is having 2 requests the first one is showing post but the response data is showing "Object moved here". What can be done to avoid that? I have added the screenshot of the same along with the answer. But in the second request the request is shown as a GET request.

Comment: This is another question, ask a new one.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was thinking about the solution for the issue so when u told to post a new question I had gone for that.